# Facebook friendliest for android app using graph API

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-fragments

Hi I am trying to get the Facebook friends list integrated in my app. I have already gotten the permissions, and can log in and everything. Implemented the Facebook graph API but when i tried running it these are the error I am getting. I would appreciate it if someone could help me out. Also this is the error stack that I am getting

04-04 19:50:32.663 1979-1979/com.example.brianberg.moomie2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 19:50:32.663 1979-1979/com.example.brianberg.moomie2 E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.brianberg.moomie2, PID: 1979
04-04 19:50:32.663 1979-1979/com.example.brianberg.moomie2 E/AndroidRuntime: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.brianberg.moomie2/com.example.brianberg.moomie2.Friends_Fragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
04-04 19:50:32.663 1979-1979/com.example.brianberg.moomie2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1794)
04-04 19:50:32.663 1979-1979/com.example.brianberg.moomie2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1512)
04-04 19:50:32.663 1979-1979/com.example.brianberg.moomie2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3917)
04-04 19:50:32.663 1979-1979/com.example.brianberg.moomie2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatJB.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompatJB.java:30)
04-04 19:50:32.663 1979-1979/com.example.brianberg.moomie2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:162)
04-04 19:50:32.663 1979-1979/com.example.brianberg.moomie2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:918)
04-04 19:50:32.663 1979-1979/com.example.brianberg.moomie2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:1008)
04-04 19:50:32.663 1979-1979/com.example.brianberg.moomie2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:921)
04-04 19:50:32.663 1979-1979/com.example.brianberg.moomie2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:910)
04-04 19:50:32.663 1979-1979/com.example.brianberg.moomie2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.brianberg.moomie2.MainFragment$1$3.onCompleted(MainFragment.java:82)
04-04 19:50:32.663 1979-1979/com.example.brianberg.moomie2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.GraphRequest$5.run(GraphRequest.java:1379)
04-04 19:50:32.663 1979-1979/com.example.brianberg.moomie2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
04-04 19:50:32.663 1979-1979/com.example.brianberg.moomie2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-04 19:50:32.663 1979-1979/com.example.brianberg.moomie2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
04-04 19:50:32.663 1979-1979/com.example.brianberg.moomie2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
04-04 19:50:32.663 1979-1979/com.example.brianberg.moomie2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-04 19:50:32.663 1979-1979/com.example.brianberg.moomie2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
04-04 19:50:32.663 1979-1979/com.example.brianberg.moomie2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing an Activity declaration in your AndroidManifest.xml.
This activity is likely the parent activity of Friends_Fragment.

PS: You also need to include the FacebookActivity in your manifest, here's an example:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        />
```

Comment: When I try to declare it with android:name="Friends_Fragment" I get this error saying "Friends_Fragment is not assignable to android.appActivity"

Comment: You need to declare the activity that hosts Friends_Fragment. On an unrelated note, you should camel case your class names rather than use underscores (FriendsFragment).

Comment: Aight, its starting to make a little sense. So my Friends_Fragment class is inheriting from a class called Fragment. Do I need to declare that as an activity? Sorry for so many questions, this is my first time building an app

Comment: Your fragment should be hosted inside an activity. You cannot show a fragment on its own (well, you can using some tricks with the WindowManager, but let's not get into that). If you edit your question and include your code structure outlining your activities and fragments, post some of your manifest.xml where you declare the activities, and provide the code where you attempt to show the Friends_Fragment, I can help further.

Comment: I think my problem is that my Friends_Fragment is a fragment and not an activity, which is why I am getting the error. The place where the compiler expects an activity, it sees a fragment instead. I don't know how to post code snippets here. If you could tell me that I would post my code snippet as well.